# alternative to finish() method for Service class? To kill it dead

Tags: android, service, kill, activity-finish

I have used the method finish() before in several activities without problems.

however when I tried to call it inside of the broadcast receiver I get the error message from the compiler that "the method finish() is undefined for the type AudioService"

AudioService is the name of my Service class in my Android app.

If there is no finish() method in a Service than what can I call to kill this Service dead?

Comment: stopSelf is the method to stop a service from itself

Comment: we have stopservice .. and stopself .. options.. you should try with one of those..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

use this line:

```
this.stopSelf();
```

to kill itself.

Or from outside use `stopService(intent);`

Answer (score 5):

you can try as to stop your  `AudioService`  service from broadcast receiver :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(context, AudioService.class); 
context.stopService(intent);
```

where `context` is first param which you received in on Receive of broadcast receiver