# finishActivity doesn't recognize in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, activity-finish

I previously start speech recognition service from `MainActivity` by `startActivityForResult` and put `onActivityResult` also in the main. I also stop the service by finishActivity in the `MainActivity`. All work O.K.

Now I pass the active of the service to the `Fragment` and also the `onActivityResult` in the `Fragment`. It get there the replay. But when i put the finishActivity in the `Fragment` it mark it in red and didn't recognize it.

It is look it need activity so I add before `getActivity.finishActivity(THE REQUEST CODE)` and it run. But it is look that it doesn't close the service any more.
Where could be the problem?
Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.stopSelf() if in the same service

Or inside your onActivityResult try calling stopService(intent)

Refer

[alternative to finish() method for Service class? To kill it dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968904/alternative-to-finish-method-for-service-class-to-kill-it-dead)

for the same

Answer (score 0):

See [startActivityForResult() from a Fragment and finishing child Activity, doesn't call onActivityResult() in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17085729/238753). The problem is the fragment's `startActivityForResult()` is remapping your request code, but the `getActivity().finishActivity()` is not mapping back. You need to start the activity from `MainActivity` instead of the fragment.